# Is it a bad idea to list every function/method argument on a new line and why?

Tags: coding-style

I work with someone who, every time they call a function they put the arguments on a new line e.g.

```
aFunction(
    byte1,
    short1,
    int1, 
    int2,
    int3,
    int4,
    int5
) ;
```

I find this very annoying as it means the code isn't very compact, so I have to scan up and down more to actually make any sense of the logic. I'm interested to know whether this is actually bad practice and if so, how can I persuade them not to do it?

Comment: +1, I don't know enough to answer your question, but I hate this as well.  If you have that many arguments in a function however then your function is probably doing too much.

Comment: More to the point, why do we still have to see each others preferences about this? why can't our IDEs just automatically present it in whatever style we want?

Comment: You say it means the code isn't very compact. But then I see people using high-res screens so they can see a lot of code, but then they puff it up with whitespace, like putting each `{` on its own line, that pushes other code off-screen. I assume these are just matters of what people are used to, nothing more.

Comment: Mike, I like having code take up minimal screen real estate. But it's a compromise. I put { on a separate line because it makes it easier to match with the closing } and correctly understand the scope of the block. It's worth the tradeoff of losing a line of screen real estate.

Comment: @Alex: You're totally right.  I think the right thing to do would be to have a language where the parse tree of the code is stored on disk, and displayed according to user preferences.

Comment: I don't actually mind that. Having the commas at the end of the line though... grrr

Comment: @AlexFeinman, messes up the debugging part.

Comment: @Ben: Where would you have the commas, then?

Comment: @AlexBrault in front of the variables. If you miss one or have an extra one it's really easy to see where you've gone wrong. It also, in my opinion, makes things look prettier and makes things more readable as you can line the commas up.

Comment: @Ben that sounds far more like OCD than valid code formatting. On the opposite side of the argument, your eye is unable to track variable names as easily when you scan down the list because it will constantly have to skip the comma--a task that is more difficult than skipping whitespace.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I don't understand how whitespace would mess up debugging. Why not build whitespace-aware debuggers?

Comment: Personally i like less lines, but sometimes i feel i need them like in angular. My related question about angular services dependencies.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113539/what-is-best-practices-indentation-for-angular-dependency-injection-syntax?noredirect=1#comment59873951_36113539

Comment: @maple_shaft I despise statements like that. Not because there isn't any truth to it, but because too many people follow such advice without leaving room for nuance.

Answer (score 43):

It's just a coding guideline which you may or may not like. The important thing is that you and your colleagues agrees to use it or not.

Obviously, the best way to increase readability is to limit the number of arguments.

Comment: Too many people reduce arguments by dumping them in an array. I'd rather see an ugly mess than cleaner-looking code with hidden complexity.

Comment: Arrays aren't the way to go. There might be a structure hiding in the args, or maybe the function is doing too much and should be split up.

Comment: I find that using multiple lines help to make the code readable IF parameters are long expression or a few too many. Otherwise it's just annoying.

Comment: Putting them in a data transfer object just moves the problem.  If all the arguments are required, then they all have to be mandatory arguments of the DTO's constructor, which means you still have that many arguments.

Answer (score 25):

It's a matter of preference. For complicated function calls where you want to document each parameter, or where the variables are rather long and there are many of them, this can be good.

For example:

```
do_complex_op(
      0, //Starting state, always 0, ask Joe why
      X, //X-coord of thingy
      y, //Y-coord of thingy
      73, //in this case, we don't want to use Z but want constant 
      dlogMessageTitle, //message for dialogue title
      dlogMessageText, //message for dialogue contents, don't care about this.
      SomethingIP, //IP of something-or-other server, can be NULL, won't crash.
      someObject.childObject.getValue(key1).HVAL, //very long path to HVAL
      someObject.childObject.getValue(key1).LVAL, //very long path to LVAL
      this.parentWindow.owner.mainTextBox.text.value.trim, //get the trimmed text, untrimmed text causes weird output
      pvrMainSettingForLongBlahs.getObjectByPath(somePath),
      pvrMainSettingForLongBlahs.K_TCA_UPPER_LIMIT,
      pvrMainSettingForLongBlahs.K_ENDPOINT_COMPLIANCE_LEVEL,
 );
```

With languages that allow named parameters this is more common if you use the parameter names (example is in PL/SQL):

```
PKG_SOME_TEST_CODE.FN_DO_SOMETHING( in_text => 'test text',
                                    in_id => v_id,
                                    in_ref_id => v_ref_id,
                                    out_array_for_storage => v_bArray);
```

But I agree with you that if the function call is simple and not too many parameters, this could get annoying, such as:

```
setColour (
    r,
    g,
    b
 );
```

I find much easier to read as

```
 setColour(r,g,b);
```

---

For @ammoQ:

```
rc=a(b,c(d,e(f)))

rc=a(
     b,
     c(
       d,
       e(
         f
        )
      )
    )
```

Comment: The first example is a wrong answer to a real problem. Why not use explicit variable anmes in the first place ?

Comment: @deadalnix: Good point, cleaned it up a bit.

Comment: True. However, it's not always an issue with variable names. It's more to do with long variable names, arguments with default values, etc

Comment: I would argue the better solution to the problem is to refactor do_complex_op() so it takes a structure as a parameter.  Then you can do `do_complex_op(new paramStruct { StartingState = 0, XCoord = xcoord })`, then it becomes self documenting and much easier to read

Comment: @KallDrexx: I agree, but sometimes changing the code is not an option, such as when it's a function in someone else's library. Sure, I could make a wrapper to it, but I'll still have to call *their original* function at some point.

Comment: Yeah that's true.

Comment: +1 Your answer is the one I most agree with. I annoy people even further by putting the comma before the argument, as in `, theArg`. I don't do this for appearance. I do it for ease of changing the argument list, which is more often done by adding or removing arguments at the end of the list than at the beginning or middle, IME.

Comment: I wonder how one would format nested functions calls, e.g. `rc=a(b,c(d,e(f)))` according to the one-argument-per-line rule.

Comment: @ammoQ: Updated, just for you!!

Comment: I agree, but I think the num of arguments should be controlled less than 5.

Comment: Thanks. I must admit, I expected that, though it definitely frightens me.

Comment: @ammoQ: I have worked with teams (from a company that mine was working with) that had standards similar to this and it was enforced a little too rigidly, IMO. If this frightens you, the way they formatted their SQL queries would make you soil yourself!

Comment: I don't like the use of magic numbers in the first example. This is also an example of something that I see a lot of (comments for each argument). I also think this reduces readability but isn't necessarily the wrong thing to do. I would argue that the long paths should be put into local descriptive variables and the comments thrown away.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: I'd really love to throw one of my rather complex queries at them and watch(1) them format it.  (1) from a safe distance

Comment: @inspectorG4dget When you get long name to be explicit, then you have a conception problem in your code. The name always belongs to a context : namespace, class name, function name. If that context doesn't allow you to have a short explicit name, it just means that the variable doesn't belong here at all and should be used elsewhere.

Comment: is there any standard about it? any documentation or something?

Answer (score 12):

Well, here's some downvote-bait.
I've never been accused of doing the popular thing.
Clearly, if things fit on one line, then fine, fit them on one line.

But my main concern is not whether the code is "ugly" or "pretty".
My main concern is how easy it is to understand and make changes to without making mistakes.

If the arguments are long and there are a lot of them, why not put them on separate lines?
To my mind that makes it easier to see what they are, and easier to change them if necessary.
It also gives me room to attach a comment to each argument if I want to.

I also want to minimize the chance of making a mistake if I add or remove an argument to a function, which is more likely to happen at the end of an argument list than at the beginning.
For that reason, I prefer to put the comma (,) at the beginning of a line, than at the end.
Then, if for example, I want to remove or add an argument at the end of the list, it's a one-line edit.
I don't have to go fiddle with the comma that needs to go at the end of all lines but the last, where the last has to end with a parenthesis.

So (boy, I'm gonna get flamed for this) I write it like this:

```
nameOfFunction(firstArgument
    , secondArgument // optional comment
       ...
    , lastArgument   // optional comment
    );
```

When there's a function with from five to twenty arguments, the function didn't get that way all at once.
It grew over time, meaning there were lots of edits.
Any edit not completed is a syntax error or a bug.
So I don't claim this is pretty.
I claim it helps in getting the edits right.

(And for those who say I should pass a structure instead, all that does is displace the issue, because you need a bunch of lines of code to fill in the structure, not to mention the extra code to declare and allocate it.)

Comment: I personally think this is a great answer because you explained your reasoning very well. Good job Mike.

Answer (score 10):

IMO everything that is uncommon *is* bad practice unless it's superiority over the usual style can be positively proven. “Matter of taste“ is a poor excuse for writing code that is harder to read than necessary for the majority of programmers, because one day, a poor soul, not used to that style, will have to maintain that code.

Proving that it's uncommon is relatively easy, show the source of examples in MSDN or similar sites, show large open-source code bases etc. Show the output of code beautifiers. Ultimately, show how everbody else in *your* team is doing it. Don't accept a bad style just because someone is too stubborn.

Comment: Hm... with that approach, how could we ever introduce a new best practice (or, gramatically correct: a *better practice*)?

Comment: Treb: Sure, just show that the better practice is in fact *better*, not just *different*.

Comment: But "harder to read" is, itself, subjective and a matter of opinion.  For me, one argument per line is easier to parse visually than two, three, or four arguments per line. And I always break a call into multiple lines if it extends beyond approx the 100 character mark in the editor.

Comment: Toby: Everthing that is not formatted the way you are used to is, at least in the first moment, harder to read.

Comment: Meh. "Harder to read" _can_ be measured objectively. It just tends not to be. Arguing about it is more fun.

Comment: it can be measured objectively but not independently of the person doing the reading.

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't call it either. Best practice where I've worked has typically been to have function calls be all on one line, unless you would have to scroll horizontally any significant amount to see the entire call. Its a judgement call, but I would definitely say that to put *all* functions like this is out of line unless that is the standard established by your organization.

This is why it is good practice for an organization to establish a set of guides to which all programmers should adhere. Its all about consistency and readability.

Answer (score 8):

It makes it easier to:

- Reorder arguments.
- Comment out or disable arguments.
- See exactly which argument has changed when you view diffs in your version control system
- Avoid re-indenting and word-wrapping everything when you add or remove an argument, or change the function name. (Even if your editor automatically indents, you are still creating lots of unhelpful whitespace changes which make it harder to follow changes in your version control system.)

Answer (score 4):

I would say that function calls should be all on one line unless they significantly exceed whatever your standard code width is (often 80 characters, often a cause of arguments :-).

I don't see any advantage to this style.  It looks subjectively ugly, and I find it a pain when searching code.  For instance you might want to quickly search and see whether the function is ever called with a certain parameter passed as NULL.  This is easy visually when all parameters are on one line, and harder when they are split like this.

Comment: This 80 character thing has to go, there just aren't any technically-valid reasons for it anymore.  We now live in an era of 19xx X 16xx monitors and adjustable fonts AND font sizes.

Comment: @anon: Valid reasons for it? Why do you think text is printed in columns and books are narrower than they could be? Because the human eye loses track when reading across very long lines.

Comment: @anon: Also I like to use my widescreen to have two or three files open in a horizontal split which gets back to 80-100 characters in a line.

Comment: @anon: Technically no, practically: hell YES. Zan Lynx is completely right, plus there are additional reasons: merging, diff, using command line utilities... Oh and good luck focusing on 8p font as you'll get older :o)

Answer (score 3):

I've frequently seen that style on function *declarations* or *definitions*, but never on a call (until now).  There it makes sense sometimes as it lets you add a comment for individual parameters more clearly.  It seems like he copied that style to calls without really knowing the underlying reasons behind it.  You have a good argument against and he doesn't seem to have a good one for, so you have my vote, but I'm not the one you have to convince.

Comment: I see both on calls.  If the parameter list is too long, it should be broken across multiple lines.  If the parameters don't group normally within width limits, I expect them to be on separate lines.  If the function and parameter names fit well on one line, then I often see them arranged that way.

Answer (score 2):

Is it against the company coding standards?

If not, then initiate a discussion about the standards and what people would like to see changed. Make sure you bring this up as one of the things you'd like to change.

Have a full discussion about *why* you don't think this is useful and hopefully you'll win the day. You never know your colleague might convince you that his way is the best after all ;)

Once you've got an updated standard then it's documented what everyone should be coding to, so if your colleague persists in doing this you can raise it in his code reviews.

Answer (score 2):

It may look funky to you but it makes working on code easier.  While refactoring you can comment out individual arguments very easily and check your refactor before actually deleting things.  You can also comment out and temporarily replace types quite easily.

It's also easier to read than:

```
int f(int, int, int,
      char, double, int
      X const&, Y)
{}
```

I have not gone as extreme as you're showing (since there's no names on the parameters it is not much use), but I have gotten into the habit of either splitting each parameter on its own line or not doing splitting at all.

The important part is that your code can be printed or displayed on standard, 80col displays and still be legible.

Answer (score 2):

You'll rarely get an honest answer out of a programmer for something like this.  Everyone will just answer with what they do or do not prefer.  The truth is that, as much we all struggle with it at times, the only "bad practice" here is your own inflexibility.

You have to be brutally honest with yourself to be able to distinguish between things that are actually bad and things that just annoy you.  The truth is that in C/C++ and similar languages you will rarely find an indentation practice that has a tangible affect on the understandability of the code.  Most discussions about these sorts of things just have both sides stacked with people making ridiculous, disingenuous arguments to try to justify their own personal preference.

Which to my reading... is exactly what you're requesting in this question: a ridiculous, disingenuous argument to justify your personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it depends on the person.. I would say for complex functions as demonstrated by FrustratedWithForms first example, then yes; otherwise a big NO. Then again this is why I prefer to apply the IDE functionality of code arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm interested to know whether this is actually bad practice..."

Yes, it's bad practice, except when the list of variables is abnormally long. But in that case, the problem is likely due to the function's design. Why not pass an object that encapsulates many of the parameters?

"...and if so, how can I persuade them not to do it?"

Tie them down and keep tickling them until they agree to stop that crap.

Comment: *"Why not pass an object that encapsulates many of the parameters?"* OK, now you've moved the problem to that new object. It still needs the same amount of parameters (via its constructor, for example), so you still have the same problem.

Answer (score -2):

Why are you wasting cycles on such a trivial concern? Just fire up your trusty IDE, open the file, and reformat. Voila! It will be in whatever form you want.

Now let's move on to the really important issue--vi or emacs, LOL.

Comment: And then when you come to check that into source-control?

Answer (score -2):

I would say, if the arguments fit on one line, do so. If not, then one argument per line makes for great readability.

```
foo(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5)
```

vs.

```
foo(
    arg1=arg1,
    arg2=arg2,
    arg3=arg3,
    arg4=arg4,
    arg5=arg5,
    arg6=arg6,
    arg7=arg7
)
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to offer anything substantial over points made and explained in prior 14 answers